# Cassandra -f Can't find dependent libraries java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, dll, cassandra

```
Exception (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) encountered during startup: 
C:\Users\chand\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-94623570\jna4591461042706372094.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\chand\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-94623570\jna4591461042706372094.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:606)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:789)

ERROR 14:10:52 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\chand\AppData\Local\Temp\jna-94623570\jna4591461042706372094.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:851) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:826) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:140) ~[jna-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2 (b0)]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WindowsTimer.<clinit>(WindowsTimer.java:35) ~[apache-cassandra-3.0.22.jar:3.0.22]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:606) [apache- 
cassandra-3.0.22.jar:3.0.22]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:789) [apache-cassandra-3.0.22.jar:3.0.22]
```

Even I tried with different versions of Cassandra but still I was getting the same error. Any fix would be appreciated

Update:

```
OS Windows 10
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)
Python 2.7.18
apache-cassandra-3.0.22
```

Above are system and application version

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and this was due to AdoptOpenJdk and I switched to Red Hat JDK and the cassandra started working.

Answer (score 0):

download red hat open jdk 1.8.0_282

[image]

Cassandra will work now